# Condition for the last row of CSV file in JAVA

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, filereader

I need to know if I am in the last line of my CSV file or no.

My code is like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(MyCSVFile));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
// Doing some actions

//I need to define here; If it is the last row, do another action

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Sin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```java
String lastLine = "";

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
  // Doing some actions

  // Overwrite lastLine each time
  lastLine = line;
}

// now do something with lastLine
System.out.println("This is the last line: " + lastLine);
```

Comment: I literally came here to post an almost identical answer. GW :)